# Magento2: {"0":"Class argument is invalid:

Tags: magento2, translate

we have issue with extension translate language MageCube on  our magento version latest 2.3.4 and when we try open catalog with products then get issue:

```
{"0":"Class argument is invalid: MageCubeTeam\\LanguageTranslatorMultilingual\\Ui\\Component\\ProductOptions","1":"#1 Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Argument\\InterpreterInterface\\Proxy->evaluate() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Data\/Argument\/Interpreter\/Composite.php:61]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Argument\\Interpreter\\Composite->evaluate() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-ui\/Config\/Data.php:164]\n#3 Magento\\Ui\\Config\\Data->evaluateComponentArguments() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-ui\/Config\/Data.php:167]\n#4 Magento\\Ui\\Config\\Data->evaluateComponentArguments() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-ui\/Config\/Data.php:167]\n#5 Magento\\Ui\\Config\\Data->evaluateComponentArguments() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-ui\/Config\/Data.php:167]\n#6 Magento\\Ui\\Config\\Data->evaluateComponentArguments() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-ui\/Config\/Data.php:111]\n#7 Magento\\Ui\\Config\\Data->initData() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-ui\/Config\/Data.php:136]\n#8
```

Can anyone help how to solve?

Comment: the exception is thrown in `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Argument\Interpreter\ConfigurableObject::evaluate()`. maybe you can start debugging in there

Comment: Also, their extension page on marketplace says the module is compatible with 2.2 only.